# send a post to bot framework directline with Axios - ERROR

Tags: javascript, axios, botframework

I'm trying to start a conversation with a bot, directline and axios.
I need start conversations with chatBot for runing automated test
See the simple code I create:

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const app = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

const token ='**********************' //

const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: '*/*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2',
      'Content-Length': 0
    },
  }

axios.post('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/G7mwbcHfDn3Izb44KCt2ql-br/activities', config).then(resp => {
 console.log(resp.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error.toJSON());
      });
```

the only response I get is this:

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\CampanhK\Desktop\express\meu-primeiro-express-client\testand.js"
{
  message: 'Request failed with status code 403',
  name: 'AxiosError',
  description: undefined,
  number: undefined,
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  columnNumber: undefined,
  stack: undefined,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2',
      'Content-Length': 190
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/G7mwbcHfDn3Izb44KCt2ql-br/activities',
    data: '{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer ******************************",
   "Accept":"*/*",
   "Content-Type":"application/json",
   "User-Agent":"axios/0.27.2",
   "Content-Length":0}}'
  },
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  status: 403
```

I've tried several alternatives but I just got this error
any help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this part of documentation.

[Non Reply Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?source=recommendations&view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-a-non-reply-message)

You need to send an activity object in the request body.

[Activity Object Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object)

To make it using axios, add data field in Axios Config.

```
let config = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   headers: headers,
   data: activity
};

axios(config).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((err)=> {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Do you know how I can send messages to the bot? documentation is a bit confusing.

Thanks for the help.